# How to save automatically in different xls using "with open" in python?

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I want to save some data in different Excel sheets using `with open` in a `for` loop.

E.g. when `i=1,2,3,4`, I want to save the following Excel sheets: `1.xls, 2.xls, 3.xls, 4.xls`

Here's my code:

```
for num in (1,2,3,4):       
    with open(r'C:\Users\Batman\Desktop\num.csv','a',encoding='ANSI') as f:
    f.close()
```

Apparently in this way I got only one `xls` in the target directory, num.csv

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert the number into the file name. `num.csv` is just a literal, not *interpolated*

Also, as you asked for XLS, then change the file extension

```
for num in range(1,5):  # Exclusive range       
    with open(r'C:\Users\Batman\Desktop\{0}.xls'.format(num),'a',encoding='ANSI') as f:
        pass
```

`f.close()` is not necessary when opening files in this way